# Query optimization SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, union-all

Okay so I've been trying and testing for hours on end now and I cannot seem to get my query to work any bit faster.

I have a huge query with a ton of `UNION ALL` in between them.
Sadly, the query takes about 10 seconds to execute and, of course, this is way too long for the user to wait.

it looks something like this (simplified version):

```
SELECT distinct  * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        'QUD' as typeString, 
        1 as typeInt,
        Process.END_USER_PROJECT.id,
        .......,
        1 as actionAvailable
    FROM Process.END_USER_PROJECT (nolock)
    INNER JOIN Process.EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION (nolock)
        ON externalID = Process.EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION.Id
    WHERE externalID = 1111

UNION ALL

    SELECT 'SPECS' AS typeString, 
        2 as typeInt ,
        Process.SPECIFICATION_GENERAL.id,
        ......., 
        1 as actionAvailable
    FROM Process.SPECIFICATION_GENERAL (nolock)
    INNER JOIN Process.END_USER_PROJECT (nolock) 
        ON Process.SPECIFICATION_GENERAL.EndUserProjectId = Process.END_USER_PROJECT.id
    INNER JOIN ....
    WHERE externalID = 1112

UNION ALL

    ....................

UNION ALL

    ....................

--AND SO ON...
) AS myTempTable ORDER BY typeString, ....
```

I've been looking at `VIEWS` to possibly make it work faster but it does not. It gives me about the same time to process the entire query.

I'm running out of options and I should really get this to work.;

Anyone got an idea of optimization and in particular, in my case?

Comment: In first query maybe must be `ON Process.END_USER_PROJECT.id= Process.EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION.Id` instead of `ON externalID = Process.EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION.Id`? If no, what is `externalID`?

Comment: Views, in and of themselves (and without using RDBMS specific facilities) are much like macros. They won't offer any performance enhancement, because they're effectively expanded out into the query before it's actually optimized.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I've adjusted the query a bit to post it here, it does work so it's no issue of error or anything. only performance. Damien_The_Unbeliever So how do enhance the performance itself then?

Comment: @jbl explain yourself please

Comment: What indexes do you have/have you tried?

Comment: Instead of views you could maybe use triggers to compute a table containing the final result, and maitain it after each database update.

Comment: If this is a MSSQL server please post the execution plan or .sqlplan file so we can see what is taking time and where.

Comment: Try without `DISTINCT`. Then comment back if it helps. I'll give you another option :)

Comment: I cannot go without distinct because then, obviously, I have duplicates.

Comment: @Tikkes just try without and say if it helps. Then we will know about bottleneck

Comment: Tried, still takes over 8-9 seconds. so no improvement. @Namphibian how do I post the sqlplan? I have no remote server to put it on atm.

Comment: not at a SQL server at the moment and my Syntax is rusty. You can use the following command at the top of the query to return the SQL execution plan in XML. RUn this SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON execute it comment it out then run the query it will return a xml string. Copy the contents of the XML string into new text document and save with .sqlplan extension. You could then post this somewhere for us to have a look. You might need to experiment with my steps like I said not at a SQL server at the moment in transit!

Comment: [SQL PLAN HERE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ifDEFbysG0c0c5SmFpRUJuNlU/edit)

Put it on Google Drive.

Comment: Just tried using `WITH` statements, no luck on that either. I'm not sure what I should try next. I've been looking at websites and blogs on performance with SQL but no luck so far. I'll keep looking but still hope someone has an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

you should at least have an index on externalID:

```
Create index [indexname] on [tablename] (externalID)
```